# How to see number of tests and assertions

Tags: unit-testing, racket

I'm writing unit tests with [rackunit](https://docs.racket-lang.org/rackunit/index.html), like this:

```
(module+ test
  . . .
  (test-case ":edge"
    (let ([g (make-graph '(:edge ((:node letter a) out)
                                  ((:node letter b) in)))])
      (check-equal? (all-edges g) (set (set '(a out) '(b in))))))
  (test-case ":edge betw refs"
    (let ([g (make-graph 'a 'b '(:edge (a out) (b in)))])
      (check-equal? (all-edges g) (set (set '(a out) '(b in))))))
  . . .
  )
```

When I run the source file in DrRacket and all the tests pass, it prints nothing. It only prints something if there is an error.

When I run `raco test <source-file>`, it prints:
    49 tests passed
but not the number of assertions.

How can I get DrRacket and `raco test` to print both the number of test cases and the number of assertions?

I'd like to always see both the number of test cases and the number of assertions, because this is a good, quick confirmation of whether a test or assertion that I just added really got run: the number increases from the previous run.

Comment: It's not clear to me what assertion mechanism you're describing, and (unless I'm blind) I don't see any uses of an assertion mechanism in the code you posted. Can you include this information in your question? Or perhaps by 'assertion' you mean 'check-equal?'

Comment: @JohnClements Yes, by "assertion", I meant `check-equal?` (and all other `check*` functions).

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the word "test" is slightly overloaded here. To see this, try running the following code with `raco test`:

```
#lang racket

(require rackunit)

(define (f x) x)

(check-equal? (f 3) 3)
(check-equal? (f 3) 4)
```

Note that there are no uses of "test-case" in this code. However, running it at the
command-line produces the output:

```
raco test: "/tmp/gg.rkt"
--------------------
FAILURE
name:       check-equal?
location:   gg.rkt:8:0
actual:     3
expected:   4
--------------------
1/2 test failures
```

That is, in the absence of the `test-case` and `test-suite` forms, each use of `check-equal?` is considered to be a test. Indeed, I think I would claim that this lightweight usage is the more common one, and I should note that it is possible to associate messages with these uses of `check-equal?`.

This doesn't directly answer your question, but I think it explains why the feature you're looking for isn't (AFAICT) currently implemented. If you want something like this, I think your best bet is to implement it yourself. For a more authoritative answer, I would pose this question on the [racket mailing list](https://lists.racket-lang.org/).